# SCRecorder : How to create SCRecordSession from local video

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use SCRecorder to customize videos. I want import somes local videos to make a longer video and save to camera roll . I use SCRecord lib to implement it. First, i make each SCRecordSegment for each local video:

```
filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp4",videoTitle]];
        // Create
        SCRecordSessionSegment *record = [[SCRecordSessionSegment alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath] info:nil];
```

Then i create RecordSession :

```
SCRecordSession *recordSession = [SCRecordSession recordSession];
[recordSession addSegment:record];
```

But it crashes when i save to camera roll .

```
- (void)saveToCameraRoll : (SCRecordSession *)recordSession{
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;


SCAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[SCAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:recordSession.assetRepresentingSegments];
exportSession.videoConfiguration.filter = nil;
exportSession.videoConfiguration.preset = SCPresetHighestQuality;
exportSession.audioConfiguration.preset = SCPresetHighestQuality;
exportSession.videoConfiguration.maxFrameRate = 35;
exportSession.outputUrl = recordSession.outputUrl;

exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
exportSession.delegate = self;
exportSession.contextType = SCContextTypeAuto;



NSLog(@"Starting exporting");

CFTimeInterval time = CACurrentMediaTime();
__weak typeof(self) wSelf = self;
[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    __strong typeof(self) strongSelf = wSelf;

    if (!exportSession.cancelled) {
        NSLog(@"Completed compression in %fs", CACurrentMediaTime() - time);
    }


    NSError *error = exportSession.error;
    if (exportSession.cancelled) {
        NSLog(@"Export was cancelled");
    } else if (error == nil) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
        [exportSession.outputUrl saveToCameraRollWithCompletion:^(NSString * _Nullable path, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];

            if (error == nil) {
                [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Saved to camera roll" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
            } else {
                [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failed to save" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
            }
        }];
    } else {
        if (!exportSession.cancelled) {
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failed to save" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        }
    }
}];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are not merging the video clips first. Here is a sample from my code

```
- (IBAction)saveToCameraRoll:(id)sender {
    [[self recorder] pause:^{
        [[HPRecordSessionManager sharedInstance] saveRecordSession:[[self recorder] session]];
        [self setRecordSession:[[self recorder] session]];

        [[self saveIndicator] startAnimating];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];

        void(^completionHandler)(NSURL *url, NSError *error) = ^(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {

            if (error == nil) {

                UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum([url path], self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
            } else {

                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
                [UIViewController displayErrorAlertWithTitle:kClipSaveToCameraRallFailedTitle message:[error localizedDescription] cancelButtonText:kClipSaveToCameraRallFailedDissmissButton];
                [[self saveIndicator] stopAnimating];
            }
        };

        [[self recordSession] mergeSegmentsUsingPreset:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality completionHandler:completionHandler];
    }];
}

- (void)video:(NSString *)videoPath didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo: (void *) contextInfo {
    [[self saveIndicator] stopAnimating];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];

    if (error == nil) {
        [UIViewController displayErrorAlertWithTitle:kClipSaveToCameraRallSuccessTitle message:kClipSaveToCameraRallSuccessMessage cancelButtonText:kClipSaveToCameraRallSuccessDissmissButton];
    } else {
        [UIViewController displayErrorAlertWithTitle:kClipSaveToCameraRallFailedTitle message:[error localizedDescription] cancelButtonText:kClipSaveToCameraRallFailedDissmissButton];
    }

}
```